# What is the key combination to move an application to a different workspace in Lubuntu?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, configuration, workspaces

Is there a hot-key combination to move application between different workspaces in Lubuntu? I'm looking for a key combination similar to Ctlr-Alt-Shift  (Ubuntu). I tried modifying the `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` file but I could not get the right commands to switch applications. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setting the shortcut

*The command*

To move an application (-window) to another workspace from command, you need `wmctrl` to be installed. The command you need to move the frontmost application (-'s window) to a specific workspace (on Lubuntu) is:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -t 1
```

where `1` refers to the targeted workspace. The first workspace is `0`, so the command above will move the active window to the second workspace.

*Shortcuts in Lubuntu*

In Lubuntu, to set custom shortcuts, (indeed) you have to manually edit the file `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`. 
The easiest way to get the right syntax is to move to the `keyboard` section of the file, and simply copy an existing shortcut section, like the example below:

```
   <!-- move window to workspace 2 on Ctrl + Alt + Y-->
    <keybind key="C-A-Y">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -t 1</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
```

As a test, I added the section, and it worked fine (after log out/in); it moved the active window to the corresponding workspace on the shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

#### What you should keep in mind:

- The command needs `wmctrl` to be installed:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wmctrl
  ```
- It takes a log out/in to start working
- The first workspace has index `0`, so the command in the example actually moves the active window to the second workspace.

A more detailed instruction on adding custom shortcut keys and the used syntax, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard), in the section further down; *Create New Keyboard shortcuts* Also [here,](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) you can find a.o. how to "mention" the keys in your shortcut section:

```
Key combination

KEY-COMBINATION is the key combination which you want to bind to the actions. The format for the KEY-COMBINATION is: Modifier-Modifier-Key. Any number of modifiers (0 or more) can be used together, and they are each separated by a "-". Multiple KEY-COMBINATION can be specified in one keybind by separating them with spaces. This is useful if you use multiple keybinds for a thing that is quite complicated to specify.
Modifiers
Modifier keys   
S   Shift key
C   Control key
A   Alt key
W   Super key (Usually bound to the Windows key on keyboards which have one)
M   Meta key
H   Hyper key (If it is bound to something)

You can also use Mod1 through Mod5 as the modifiers to directly select a modifier mask (e.g. Mod1 to select Mod1Mask), but this is for advanced users who have customized their modifier mapping with xmodmap.
```

#### More "sophisticated" options

You *could* create a script to see what is the current workspace, and move the active window to the next/previous one, instead of having to set a key combination for every (targeted) workspace.

That would however be another question :)

Answer (score 0):

On Lubuntu Lxqt 0.14.1:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow (left or right)</kbd>